# Getting the raw base64 content out of an attachment in Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

So I have an attachment on my incoming Pop3 message, 
`Msg.MessageParts.Items[msgpart] as TidAttachmentFile`
but, is it possible to get the content of this attached file in the format specified by `Msg.MessageParts.Items[msgpart].ContentTransfer` (so base64 ascii) instead of creating a temp file, calling SaveToFile, and then re-reading the file and re-connverting back to base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TIdMessage.NoDecode` is set to False, then no, it is not possible.  When `NoDecode` is False, `TIdMessageClient` decodes the email as it is being read off the socket and places decoded binary data into attachment objects.  The only way to get the original base64 data is to set `TIdMessage.NoDecode` to True and parse the raw email data manually (it is stored as-is in the `TIdMessage.Body`) as you would effectively be disabling `TIdMessageClient's` entire decoding system.

On the other hand, if you just want to avoid the temp file, you can use the `TIdMessage.OnCreateAttachment` event to have Indy create `TIdAttachmentMemory` objects instead of the default `TIdAttachmentFile` objects. The base64 will still be auto-decoded and stored as binary in the attachment, but at least the attachment would be solely in memory so your re-encode would be faster.